# Setting limitation for running a while loop in java

Tags: java, if-statement, error-handling, while-loop

This is a simple project from my class. The User can put only wrong input 3 times if he enters more than 3 times the program should terminate. I don't know what loop should I use. Please provide some ideas. I tried using FOR loop but it's not working

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int numl = readNumber("number1", 1, 10);
    int num2 = readNumber("number2", 11, 20);
    int add = Total(numl + num2);
}

public static int readNumber(String Prompt, int min, int max) {
    int value ;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
            System.out.print(Prompt);
            value = scanner.nextInt();
            if ((value >= min && value <= max)) {
                break;
            }
        }
    return value;
}
public static int Total(int sum) {
    System.out.println("SUM = " + sum);
    return sum;
}
}
```

---

[image]

Comment: Any loop will work. Remove the image and post your code as text.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) - show CODE, not pictures of code

Comment: so, the user has 3 changes to make a mistake for every number or 3 chances for the whole application??

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ for each number he has 3 chances or in total user has 6 chances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you use `do-while` loop (it doesn't mean you can't solve it using other types of loop) because it will make the code easy to understand. A `do-while` loop guarantees that its body will be executed at least once.

You also need a variable, e.g. `int attempts` to track the number of attempts.

Do it as follows:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numl = readNumber("Number1: ", 1, 10);
        int num2 = readNumber("Number2: ", 11, 20);
        int add = Total(numl + num2);
    }

    public static int readNumber(String Prompt, int min, int max) {
        int value;
        int attempts = 0;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        do {
            System.out.print(Prompt);
            value = scanner.nextInt();
            if ((value >= min && value <= max)) {
                break;
            }
            attempts++;
        } while (attempts < 3);

        if (attempts == 3) {
            // Reset `value`
            value = 0;
        }

        return value;
    }

    public static int Total(int sum) {
        System.out.println("SUM = " + sum);
        return sum;
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Number1: 10
Number2: 15
SUM = 25
```

**Another sample run:**

```
Number1: 50
Number1: 56
Number1: -1
Number2: 23
Number2: -60
Number2: 50
SUM = 0
```

Given below is the code using `while` loop instead of a `do-while` loop:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numl = readNumber("Number1: ", 1, 10);
        int num2 = readNumber("Number2: ", 11, 20);
        int add = Total(numl + num2);
    }

    public static int readNumber(String Prompt, int min, int max) {
        int value;
        int attempts = 0;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
            if (attempts == 3) {
                // Reset `value`
                value = 0;
                break;
            }
            System.out.print(Prompt);
            value = scanner.nextInt();
            if ((value >= min && value <= max)) {
                break;
            }
            attempts++;
        }

        return value;
    }

    public static int Total(int sum) {
        System.out.println("SUM = " + sum);
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Comment: Super coding but can we not use Do-while loop and use only While loop instead.

Comment: @NaVeEdIbRaHiM - I've posted the way to do it using `while` loop. Feel free to comment in case of any doubt/issue.

Comment: superb sir . Tnx for ur reply

Answer (score 0):

Good job making an attempt with 2 different variations. The main cause of the problem is the `while(true)` segments. What you want to do is put a condition in that segment that is checked everytime an iteration is made. Since you want to check if the amount of attempts is less than some max, then you need to check that.

Note that in the modifications i've made, an IllegalStateException is thrown if the condition in the while loop segment isn't met in any of the variations, indicating that a result isn't found.

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            int numl = readNumber("number1", 1, 10, 3);

            int num2 = readNumber("number2", 11, 20, 3);

            int add = Total(numl + num2);
        } catch (IllegalStateException ise) {
            // tell user they exceeded N attempts in 1 of the 2 numbers

        }
}
```

```java
public static int readNumber(String Prompt, int min, int max, int availableAttempts) {
    int value;

    int attempts = 0;

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (attempts++ < availableAttempts) {
        System.out.print(Prompt);

        value = scanner.nextInt();

        if ((value >= min && value <= max)) {
            return value;
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalStateException();
}

public static int Total(int sum) {
    System.out.println("SUM = " + sum);

    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Hero Sir, This code you provided workes very well . But May i Know the usage of catch (IllegalStateException) and throw new  IllegalStateException. should " catch (IllegalStateException)" be defined in Main class?

Comment: If I understand your question, the usage is provided above in my example of how to use the try-catch. As for why, it makes more sense to indicate to the caller of the method that some unexpected state has occurred, such as not inputting a number within some bounds, and thus an exception is thrown instead of returning some arbitrary number like Strings#indexOf function for example which returns -1.